# Cannot flag for mod attention in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, ios-app

Using the lastest version of the iOS app (0.1.58), I am unable to flag this question for moderator attention:

https://money.stackexchange.com/q/30261/7936

I haven't tried any others.

When I try and submit my flag, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the "other"?

Comment: Yes, I am using other.

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to flag this question on version 1.60.0

Seems like this has already been fixed, try updating your app.

Comment: I just tested this is 0.1.60 and didn't have a problem. The question that I linked to here was deleted right around when I was flagging it. I wonder if it was already deleted and I was flagging a cached version.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the flagging modal, you should see an item at the bottom to do exactly this.  Is the problem that it just doesn't work?

Comment: I believe the op has selected the option and see the error on submitting the flag

Comment: That is correct. When I try to submit the flag, the error that I posted pops up. I didn't know 0.1.6 was out though, that may fix it?